# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.api' in .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tkinter, keras

I can run my gui in .py format on VSS code, but in .exe file, it can only upload the image, and stop the whole process when i tried to classify it.
This is using tensorflow == 2.7.0
keras == 2.7.0
Am I missing something to import? Or is it about my path?

```
#importing libraries
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog,Text,Label
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import image 

import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('SavedModel/my_model.h5')
class_names = ['A&W', "McDonald's", 'Pizza Hut', 'Starbucks', 'Subway']
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
   
def upload_image(): 
    global file_path
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="Select File",
                                           filetypes= (("PNG","*.png"),("JPG","*.jpg")))
    uploaded = Image.open(file_path)
    resized = uploaded.resize((368,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    sign_image.configure(image=im)
    sign_image.image = im
    show_classify_button(file_path)
    show_clear_button() 

def classify(file_path):
    global labeloutput
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    file_path, target_size=((img_height,img_width)))
    img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch
    predictions = new_model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    Output = (
    "This image most likely belongs \n to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score)))
    labeloutput = tk.Label(frameOutput,text=Output,bg="yellow",font = ('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
    labeloutput.pack()
    upload['state'] = DISABLED
    classify_btn['state'] =DISABLED

def show_classify_button(file_path):
    global classify_btn
    classify_btn = Button(root,text = "Classify Image", 
                          command = lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10,pady=5)
    classify_btn.configure(state = NORMAL,fg="#1C1C1C",bg="white", font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    classify_btn.place(relx=0.34,rely=0.77)

def show_clear_button():
    #clear button
    global ClearButton
    ClearButton = Button(root, text = "Clear Output", command= lambda: myDelete(), padx = 10,pady = 5)
    ClearButton.configure(state=NORMAL,fg="#1C1C1C",bg="white", font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    ClearButton.place(relx=0.53,rely=0.77)

def myDelete():
    labeloutput.pack_forget()
    upload['state'] = NORMAL
    ClearButton['state'] = DISABLED
   

    

#initialize GUI
root = tk.Tk()
#Define image
img = Image.open('BG2.jpg')
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
#Create a label
my_label = Label(root, image=bg)
my_label.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth =1, relheight = 1)
root.geometry('800x680')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Fast Food Restaurant Logo Classification")
root.iconbitmap('Icon.ico')

#set Heading
heading = Label(root, text = "         FAST FOOD RESTAURANT LOGO CLASSIFICATION         ", pady = 20, 
                font = ('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
heading.configure(fg="white", bg = "black") 
heading.pack()

#frame for Image Ouput
frameImage = tk.Frame(root, bd = 10, bg = 'white')
frameImage.place(relx = 0.2250, rely = 0.13, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 0.55)
#uploaded image in Frame
sign_image = Label(frameImage)
sign_image.pack()

#frame for text output
frameOutput = tk.Frame(root, bd = 10, bg = 'yellow')
frameOutput.place(relx = 0.2250, rely = 0.65, relheight = 0.08, relwidth = 0.55)

#exit button
exit = Button(root,text = "Exit", command = root.quit , padx=10, pady=5)
exit.configure(fg="white",bg="black", font=('arial',10,'bold'))
exit.place(relx = 0.4650, rely = 0.93)

#upload button
upload = Button(root,text = "Upload an Image", command = upload_image, padx=10, pady=5)
upload.configure(fg="white",bg="black", font=('arial',10,'bold'))
upload.place(relx = 0.4125, rely = 0.87)

#predicted class
label = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error that is shown on my windows console, but i do not know how to fix it,

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "FastFood.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    command = classify(file_path), padx=10,pady=5)
  File "FastFood.py", line 39, in classify
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
  File "tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
  File "tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.api'
```

Comment: Indeed given code worked on colab with Tensorflow==2.7.0 and Keras==2.7.0. Uninstall Tensorflow and Try installing tensorflow again. Thanks!